# I set count to 500 but tweepy.cursor returns only 276 tweets,how do i get 1000plus tweets?

Tags: python, tweepy

My code:

```
tweets = tweepy.Cursor(api.search,
          q=search_words,
          count=500,
          geocode="20.5937,78.9629,1000km",
          lang="en",
          since=date_since,until=date_until).items(500)
```

after saving to a pandas dataframe:
 `df.shape`
 returns (267,9)

Comment: are you sure that you should receive more than 276 tweets? Can you share your search parameters?

Comment: search_words=('Mode OR #MODI OR #COVID-19 OR CORONAVIRUS OR @PMOIndia OR BJP OR #Lockdown OR #Migrants OR #Labourers OR Lockdown extension OR #GDP OR Lockdown 3.0 -filter:retweets')
date_since = "2020-04-04"
date_until="2020-06-06" These are my search parameters and for some reason it simply won't return more 270 tweets, as you can see i mentioned a count of 500 so shouldnt it be returning that many tweets ?

Answer (score 1):

From [twitter search api](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/search/api-reference/get-search-tweets):

> Please note that Twitter's search service and, by extension, the Search API is not meant to be an exhaustive source of Tweets. Not all Tweets will be indexed or made available via the search interface.

Comment: search_words=('Mode OR #MODI OR #COVID-19 OR CORONAVIRUS OR @PMOIndia OR BJP OR #Lockdown OR #Migrants OR #Labourers OR Lockdown extension OR #GDP OR Lockdown 3.0 -filter:retweets')
date_since = "2020-04-04"
date_until="2020-06-06"